# std::find in vector with structures

Tags: c++, c++11, overload-resolution, list-initialization

I have a structure

```cpp
struct position {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

and a vector `pos` of such structures.

When I try to check whether a certain element is present in this vector, I use

```cpp
    auto it = std::find(pos.begin(), pos.end(), {x,y});
```

This, however, only works, when I explicitly pass the constructor to `std::find()` function, i.e.

```cpp
    auto it = std::find(pos.begin(), pos.end(), position({x,y}));
```

Otherwise, I get compiler error

```
    std::find: no matching overloaded function found
```

Why is that? Is it because compiler cannot deduce the type of `{x,y}` in the line above?

Comment: Since the `std::find()` function accepts a generic `const T&`, it is not possible to perform a [copy-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) in a function call expression. It is necessary to explicitly construct the object with [direct-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) and then pass it as function argument, i.e. `position{x, y}`.

Comment: `std::find` permits heterogeneous comparisons: the type of the last parameter is arbitrary, it doesn't have to match `*first` (where `first` is the iterator passed as the first parameter). In your example, the last parameter doesn't have to be `position`. But an arbitrary type cannot be deduced from a *brace-init* list.

Comment: You need at least to implement `operator==` for your struct type as there is no default comparison for structs.